# Add horizontal lines from min point to max point per category in seaborn catplot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, line

I am trying to visualize different type of "purchases" over a quarterly period for selected customers. To generate this visual, I am using a catplot functionality in seaborn but am unable to add a horizontal line that connects each of the purchased fruits. **Each line should start at the first dot for each fruit and end at the last dot for the same fruit.** Any ideas on how to do this programmatically?

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dta = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Date", "Fruit", "type"], data=[['2017-01-01','Orange', 
'FP'], ['2017-04-01','Orange', 'CP'], ['2017-07-01','Orange', 'CP'], 
['2017-10-08','Orange', 'CP'],['2017-01-01','Apple', 'NP'], ['2017-04-01','Apple', 'CP'], 
['2017-07-01','Banana', 'NP'], ['2017-10-08','Orange', 'CP']
                                                        ])
dta['quarter'] = pd.PeriodIndex(dta.Date, freq='Q')

sns.catplot(x="quarter", y="Fruit", hue="type", kind="swarm", data=dta)

plt.show()
```

This is the result:

[image].

How can I add individual horizontal lines that each connect the dots for purchases of orange and apple?

Comment: How exactly do you want to draw the line? Can you add it to the image?

Comment: Manually adding lines to image isnt an option as I am generating many such visuals/images

Comment: I meant that I wasn't sure what line you intended to use, so please try adding it freehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Each line should start at the first dot for each fruit and end at the last dot for the same fruit.

1. Use [`groupby.ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) to map the quarters to xtick positions
2. Use [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html) to find each fruit's min and max xtick endpoints
3. Use [`ax.hlines`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hlines.html) to plot horizontal lines from each fruit's min to max

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['2017-01-01', 'Orange', 'FP'], ['2017-04-01', 'Orange', 'CP'], ['2017-07-01', 'Orange', 'CP'], ['2017-10-08', 'Orange', 'CP'], ['2017-01-01', 'Apple', 'NP'], ['2017-04-01', 'Apple', 'CP'], ['2017-07-01', 'Banana', 'NP'], ['2017-10-08', 'Orange', 'CP']], columns=['Date', 'Fruit', 'type'])
df['quarter'] = pd.PeriodIndex(df['Date'], freq='Q')

df = df.sort_values('quarter')                            # sort dataframe by quarter
df['xticks'] = df.groupby('quarter').ngroup()             # map quarter to xtick position
ends = df.groupby('Fruit')['xticks'].agg(['min', 'max'])  # find min and max xtick per fruit

g = sns.catplot(x='quarter', y='Fruit', hue='type', kind='swarm', s=8, data=df)
g.axes[0, 0].hlines(ends.index, ends['min'], ends['max']) # plot horizontal lines from each fruit's min to max
```

[image]

##### Detailed breakdown:

1. `catplot` plots the xticks in the order they appear in the dataframe. The sample dataframe is already sorted by `quarter`, but the real dataframe should be sorted explicitly:

   ```
   df = df.sort_values('quarter')
   ```
2. Map the quarters to their xtick positions using [`groupby.ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html):

   ```
   df['xticks'] = df.groupby('quarter').ngroup()

   #          Date   Fruit  type  quarter  xticks
   # 0  2017-01-01  Orange    FP   2017Q1       0
   # 1  2017-04-01  Orange    CP   2017Q2       1
   # 2  2017-07-01  Orange    CP   2017Q3       2
   # 3  2017-10-08  Orange    CP   2017Q4       3
   # 4  2017-01-01   Apple    NP   2017Q1       0
   # 5  2017-04-01   Apple    CP   2017Q2       1
   # 6  2017-07-01  Banana    NP   2017Q3       2
   # 7  2017-10-08  Orange    CP   2017Q4       3
   ```
3. Find the min and max `xticks` to get the endpoints per `Fruit` using [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

   ```
   ends = df.groupby('Fruit')['xticks'].agg(['min', 'max'])

   #         min  max
   # Fruit           
   # Apple     0    1
   # Banana    2    2
   # Orange    0    3
   ```
4. Use [`ax.hlines`](https://matplotlib.org/3.5.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hlines.html) to plot a horizontal line per `Fruit` from min-endpoint to max-endpoint:

   ```
   g = sns.catplot(x='quarter', y='Fruit', hue='type', kind='swarm', s=8, data=df)
   ax = g.axes[0, 0]
   ax.hlines(ends.index, ends['min'], ends['max'])
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to enable the horizontal grid for the chart as follows:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

dta = pd.DataFrame(
    columns=["Date", "Fruit", "type"],
    data=[
        ["2017-01-01", "Orange", "FP"],
        ["2017-04-01", "Orange", "CP"],
        ["2017-07-01", "Orange", "CP"],
        ["2017-10-08", "Orange", "CP"],
        ["2017-01-01", "Apple", "NP"],
        ["2017-04-01", "Apple", "CP"],
        ["2017-07-01", "Banana", "NP"],
        ["2017-10-08", "Orange", "CP"],
    ],
)


dta["quarter"] = pd.PeriodIndex(dta.Date, freq="Q")
sns.catplot(x="quarter", y="Fruit", hue="type", kind="swarm", data=dta)
plt.grid(axis='y')
plt.show()
```

Preview

[image]

Comment: Thank you Kha. The line needs to start at the first dot and end at the last dot for each fruit. I added this clarification in my question above as well to make sure it is clearer.